# How to add an active class to a Wordpress menu item when the page is not a child of that menu item?

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress, I have set up a file named 'single-event.php' which I am using to render the full data for each post from a Custom Post Type called "Events".

I also have an 'events' page, which pulls some teaser info and a permalink for each post.

However, as the single event pages (using the single-event.php template) are not children of the events page they do not get a .current-page-ancestor class added to the events menu item.

I have seen a suggestion to use the body class and nav item ID to highlight the 'events' menu item, however, the client may reorder or rename pages, and this approach may then break.

Any better suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 1):

I reccomend trying `nav_menu_css_class` filter to add the "active" classes `current-menu-item` and `current_page_item` to the menu item based on the current loaded template.

`apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', string[] $classes, WP_Post $item, stdClass $args, int $depth )`

something like this

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'my_menu_class_filter', 10, 2);

function my_menu_class_filter($classes, $item){
  global $post;
  if($item->ID !== 123){return $classes;} //Replace the ID with the id of your events teaser page
  if($post->post_type === 'event'){
    $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
    $classes[] = 'current_page_item';
  }
  return $classes;
}
```

edit: Variation for the child page

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'my_menu_class_filter', 10, 2);

function my_menu_class_filter($classes, $item){
  global $post;
  if($item->ID !== 123){return $classes;} //Replace the ID with the id of your events teaser page
  if($post->post_type === 'event'){
    $classes[] = 'current-page-ancestor';
    $classes[] = 'current-menu-ancestor';
    $classes[] = 'current-menu-parent';
    $classes[] = 'current-page-parent';
    $classes[] = 'current_page_parent';
    $classes[] = 'current_page_ancestor';
  }
  return $classes;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jasper, thank you for your reply. I found the page id of my event teaser page (It was 17) and I placed your code into my functions file, however, nothing changed in regard to the menu classes. For now I have implemented the CSS approach, but will revisit this when I have more time, appreciate your time to reply. Steve

Comment: Hi Steve, double check the post type is correct in the `if($post->post_type === 'event')` statement, you can find this in your URL when creating a new event `/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=product` this example is for a woocommerce product the post type would be `product`, you have to place the code in your themes function.php